# Stream a HTTP response in Java

Tags: httpresponse, fileinputstream

I want to write the response on an HTTP request to a File. However I want to stream the response to a physical file without waiting for the entire response to be loaded.

I will actually be making a request to a JHAT server for returning all the Strings from the dump. My browser hangs before the response completes as there are 70k such objects, I wanted to write them to a file so that I can scan through.

thanks in advance,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Read a limited amount of data from the HTTP stream and write it to a file stream.  Do this until all data has been handled.

Here is example code demonstrating the principle.  In this example I do not deal with any i/o errors.  I chose an 8KB buffer to be faster than processing one byte at a time, yet still limiting the amount of data pulled into RAM during each iteration.

```
final URL url = new URL("http://example.com/");
final InputStream istream = url.openStream();
final OutputStream ostream = new FileOutputStream("/tmp/data.txt");

final byte[] buffer = new byte[1024*8];
while (true) {
    final int len = istream.read(buffer);
    if (len <= 0) {
        break;
    } 
    ostream.write(buffer, 0, len);
}
```